# Using SuperUser as Global Software Bug Tracker

Tags: discussion, superuser

Should I report and ask how to workaround bugs in various software to SuperUser when I don't know the specialized project bug tracker or it is empty/abandoned?

There are already some questions about bugs and workarounds.

Asking about a bug in a small or abandoned tool at SU have more chance to succeed than to looking for for [abandoned] mail lists, forums, trackers.

Comment: That said, I think a OS bug tracking software that would be as quick and pleasant as Stackoverflow would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always ask for support about a specific problem, on a specific program. This is the point of Super User, getting answers to computer software and hardware questions.

As such, it is ok to ask

> I can't seem to make this *particular
>   function* to work, in *particular
>   program*. How to do that? Is there a
>   way to do it that I missed, maybe a workaround?

as opposed to

> Reporting that this function doesn't
>   work. Who can fix the program for me?

This is not the place for bug reports. It has to be a question, expecting an answer from **another user**, not from a developer of the program you use (or someone able to fix the program in general).

Stay on the user level.

Comment: +1, spot on.  i've seen a few questions on SU that were only answered by diving into bug reports on the project's bugtracker; there's some good synergy potential there.  but SU won't work as a replacement for the bugtracker.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very active on SU but I'd say no, definitely not. The trilogy is for *answerable questions*, not bug reports that have a huge likelihood to stay unanswered - if the official support channels are dead, development is probably dead, too.

There are already a lot of complaints about SU being sometimes used as the trash can of the trilogy. That is certainly not a trend that needs further encouragement.

Comment: Personally I use SU most often.
Also I think that there should be "everything else IT" site (linked to SU,SF,SO with "migrate" ability) and [truly trash can] "everything else, no limitations" (linked with SU,SF,SO with "migrate" ability).